# Bootstrap Modal retains my backdrop property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In a single page I call a Bootstrap modal twice by using different button. One button display the modal that allow to close by clicking anywhere, while the other button can only be closed by clicking the Close or X button.

But if I click the click anywhere button first, then the second button can be closed by clicking anywhere too.

If I click the close by clicking close button first, then the second button can also only be closed by clicking the close button.

Here is how I call the close anywhere button:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

Here is how I call the close using close button:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static',keyboard:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data attributes, use this for second button

```
<button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
open modal
```

pass {keyboard: false} to prevent closing the modal by pressing `ESC`

Comment: forgot to specify but the button call an ajax to display the modal. I am not putting the attributes in the button itself but in the ajax call.